# Django admin manytomany

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

Good day,I try in admin customize forms model with many to many fields

```
class CasinoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta():
    model = Casino

country = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CasinoCountries.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name_ru').order_by('name_ru'))
```

When i try save it, it saved but not returned selected, how return selected items

Answer (score 0):

```
class CasinoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Casino
        fields = ('country',)


    country = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CasinoCountries.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name_ru').order_by('name_ru'))
```